# ubuntu 14.04 + gnome-session-fallback : how do I lock the screen?

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

I'm running my new  ubuntu 14.04 + gnome-session-fallback.

Where can I find my good-old "lock-screen" button ? I can only see logout/shutdown in the top-right menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut.